# How to customize response structure when working with Axis2 REST web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, apache-axis

I'm using Axis2 1.4.1 to expose RESTful web services. I need to return xml structure (or any other for example ATOM xml or RSS xml or JSON structure) of my choosing. Axis2 out of the box returns it's own default xml structure (which is SOAP like). The question is what is the right way to customize this.
Is it via Handlers? Is it via Data Binding? Is it via custom MessageFormatter? What is the way and how?

Thanks

Comment: I've found AXIS2 REST support to be pitiful. If you have any luck with this come back and let us know.